# Setting shell variable from SELECT statement in Informix?

Tags: sql, informix

I am trying to take the result of a query and set the result as a variable for the name of a file. 
I have been reading posts and found that reading from a select and then setting a variable from the result causes issue however I am not following how to get around it.

If I run a direct query....

```
echo "SET isolation dirty read; Select * from  site;" | dbaccess davedb
```

I get the following response which is expected.

```
site_nuber site_ID  site_name

1          1        ALPHA
```

I have tried several variations of the below with DECLARE, INTO or AS but nothing is working. The below is the gist of what I want to accomplish.

```
#!/bin/bash
dateFormat=`date +'%Y%m%d'`

dbaccess davedb <<! 2>/dev/null
set isolation dirty read;

SELECT site_name AS $NAME
FROM site;
!

touch "/export/home/dave/"$NAME"_"$dateFormat.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways of answering this.

I'm sorely tempted to say "and that's why I wrote [SQLCMD](https://www.iiug.org/en/iiug-software-repository/#ESQL) twenty (oh, grief; no, it's thirty now — 1986!) thirty years ago".  DB-Access is very useful for all sorts of purposes, but this sort of shell scripting is not its forte, and SQLCMD was written to cover that deficiency.

```
NAME=$(sqlcmd -d davedb -e 'set isolation to dirty read' \
              -e 'select site_name from site')
```

Assuming that getting hold of SQLCMD (note, this is not the Microsoft johnny-come-lately program of the same name) is not an option, then you'll want to consider how to tweak DB-Access into submission.  It does its utmost to fight back!

Given that you want to capture the name in a shell variable, you can perhaps use:

```
cat <<'EOF' |
SET ISOLATION TO DIRTY READ;
OUTPUT TO "/dev/stdout" WITHOUT HEADINGS SELECT site_name FROM site;
EOF
dbaccess davedb - 2>/dev/null |
tr -d ' \n'
```

If you run this from the command line, you'll see the site name followed immediately by your prompt (since all the newlines — 5 of them — have been removed by the `tr` command), but that won't matter when you capture the output in a variable.

The OUTPUT statement is built into DB-Access (not the database server).  It writes the result of a SELECT statement to the named file.  I named `"/dev/stdout"` which is, on most modern Unix-like systems, the same as the process's standard output.  The WITHOUT HEADINGS qualifier makes it omit the column names from the output.  This cuts down the amount of junk emitted by the program.  If you don't have `/dev/stdout`, then you can specify a temporary file name instead, and then read the file — but that's a nuisance.

There are a number of variants on how to feed the SQL to DB-Access.  You could avoid the `cat` by using `echo` (but there's still a pipeline there), or by using a Bash [here string](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Strings) directly to DB-Access, or a [here document](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Documents) as the standard input for DB-Access, or create a `somefile.sql` containing the SQL and then passing `somefile.sql` (or even just `somefile`) as the file name in place of the `-` argument.

Assembling this into your script, you end up with a variant on:

```
dateFormat=$(date +'%Y%m%d')
NAME=$(cat <<'EOF' |
SET ISOLATION TO DIRTY READ;
OUTPUT TO "/dev/stdout" WITHOUT HEADINGS SELECT site_name FROM site;
EOF
dbaccess davedb - 2>/dev/null |
tr -d ' \n')

if [ -n "$NAME" ]
then touch "/export/home/dave/${NAME}_${dateFormat}.txt"
fi
```

The code was tested with `SELECT SITENAME FROM Systables WHERE tabid = 1` because SITENAME is a built-in function to Informix that returns the server name (and also a locally available database name — the ubiquitous `stores` database).  It isn't clear whether your `Site` table and `site_name` column stores that value or something else; in most respects, it doesn't matter.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and the script form works perfectly. Thanks again.